# Sending a data object to a backend function and then adding a table row with that data in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to send an object through a function and then add a table row to a table with the data from the object. I need to pass the "row" object to the function in the backend first. I can add table rows with vanilla JS and jQuery but I'm not sure how to properly do it in VueJS. How can I achieve this?

HTML TABLE

```
<table id="tableID"></table>
```

HTML THAT NEEDS TO BE ADDED WITH THE DATA FROM THE "ROW" OBJECT

```
<tr v-for="item in items" :key="item.Id" v-bind:id="item.Id" class="e-tr">
                                <td><input type="text" class="c-cell" v-model="item.Type"/></td>
                                <td><input type="text" class="c-cell" v-model="item.Model"/></td>
                            </tr>
```

JS

```
add: function () {
            var row = { Id: 0, Type: 0, Model: 0 };
            fetch('/Cont/Send', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                body: JSON.stringify(row)
            })
                .then(function (response) {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then(function () {
                    /*push some html here?*/
                })
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are saving the data into 'items', so you need to modify its value inside 'add' method, is also needed to keep the reference to the component itself -> 'this'.
One solution could be (using async/await):

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "MyComponent",
  data: function() {
    return {
      items: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async sendMyData() { //this uses object method syntax, arrow functions could be useful aswell
      const response = await fetch(
        "/Cont/Send", {
            //http method and headers configuration...
        }
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      this.items = Object.values(data.bpi);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

using then:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "MyComponent",
  data: function() {
    return {
      items: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    sendMyData() { //this uses object method syntax, arrow functions could be useful aswell
      const self = this; //we save the reference to this, because 'this' will have another scope inside the function passed to then(...)
      fetch("/Cont/Send", {
            // http method and headers configuration...
        }
      ).then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      self.items = data; // this will update the value and the new data should be rendered as we expected
    });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

PD. Sorry about my poor english

Comment: Thank you very much for your input, @kenuchi. I can see where this is going and I am going to attempt it in my project. I'm wondering though, how can I make it populate a new table row like the one in my example with the data from the object?

Comment: @grahamfk45c as I said, since you're iterating over 'items' the table row should be automatically rendered: v-for="item in items" <-- this will render 'tr' tag for each value in 'items'.

Comment: Ah, okay, yes. I will give it a try and let you know how it goes. Thanks!